# All pictures in fancybox are showing

Tags: fancybox, filtering, gallery

i have followed instructions for how to filter gallery according to categories and it worked but the problem that while i am scrolling it will scroll the whole pictures at the same category as shown in this pictures[Checks the thumbnails below the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH8Ee.jpg) before it was working fine but when i filter the gallery that was the result and i don't know where is the error exactly.
thanks for everyone helped me from the beginning specially @JFK
thanks for people here on stack overflow

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    // fancybox
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        modal: false, // enable regular nav and close buttons
        // add buttons helper (requires buttons helper js and css files)
  padding:0,
        helpers: {
            thumbs : {
    width : 50,
    height : 50,
   },
        } 
    });
    // filter selector
    $(".filter").on("click", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        // if we click the active tab, do nothing
        if ( !$this.hasClass("active") ) {
            $(".filter").removeClass("active");
            $this.addClass("active"); // set the active tab
            // get the data-rel value from selected tab and set as filter
            var $filter = $this.data("rel"); 
            // if we select view all, return to initial settings and show all
            $filter == 'all' ? 
                $(".fancybox")
                .attr("data-fancybox-group", "gallery")
                .not(":visible")
                .fadeIn() 
            : // otherwise
                $(".fancybox")
                .fadeOut(0)
                .filter(function () {
                    // set data-filter value as the data-rel value of selected tab
                    return $(this).data("filter") == $filter; 
                })
                // set data-fancybox-group and show filtered elements
                .attr("data-fancybox-group", $filter)
                .fadeIn(1000); 
        } // if
    }); // on
}); // ready
```

```html
<div id="galleryTab">
  <a data-rel="all" href="javascript:;" class="filter active">All Projects</a>
  <a data-rel="vil" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Villas</a>
  <a data-rel="res" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Residential and Commercial</a>
  <a data-rel="mix" href="javascript:;" class="filter">Mixed Used</a>
</div>
<div class="row"> </div> 
    <div class="col">
      <div class="galleryWrap">
        <ul id="projects">
          <li id="liproject" data-tags="Villas"><a title="Mr.Omran Villa (G+1+R)" class="fancybox villa" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="villa1" href="images/Projects/1.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/1s.jpg" alt="omran" width="240" height="160" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
          <div class="hidden"> <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="villa1" href="images/Projects/1h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/1h.jpg" alt="omran"></a> <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="villa1" href="images/Projects/12h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/12h.jpg" alt="omran"></a> </div>
          
          <div> <li data-tags="Villas"><a title="Mr.saif Villa (G+1+R)" data-tags="Villas" class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="villa2" href="images/Projects/2.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/2s.jpg" alt="saif" class="img-responsive"></a></li>
            <div class="hidden"> <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="villa2" href="images/Projects/21h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/21h.jpg" alt="saif"></a> <a class="fancybox" data-tags="Villas" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="vil" rel="villa2" href="images/Projects/22h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/22h.jpg" alt="saif"></a> </div>
            
            <div id="res"> <li data-tags="bldg"><a  title="Ajman Tower (G+8Podium+26 Typical+R)" class="fancybox" data-tags="Residential and Commercial" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="res" rel="bldg1" href="images/Projects/4.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/4s.jpg" alt="ajman" width="240" height="160" class="img-responsive" border="0"></a></li>
              <div class="hidden"> <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="res"  rel="bldg1" href="images/Projects/41h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/41h.jpg" alt="ajman"></a> <a class="fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" data-filter="res" rel="bldg1" href="images/Projects/42h.jpg"><img src="images/Projects/42h.jpg" alt="ajman"></a> </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: They show all because you have the `data-fancybox-group="gallery"` attribute on all images. Just get rid of it and let the `data-filter` do the grouping job

Comment: @JFK thanks a lot for your efforts it works and i have done my first website because of you.... i appreciate your help